Describing Complex transformation

Consider the transformation $z \to \frac{2}{1-z}$ for $z \in \mathbb{C}$. Find and describe the image of the unit circle and the line $\{x = 1\}$

Attempt:
For the unit circle, we know it has equation $|z| = 1$. So I tried the following trick $A = \frac{2}{1-z} \implies |z| = \frac{|A-2|}{|A|} \implies 1 = \frac{|A-2|}{|2|} \implies |A| = |A-2|$. I am not sure if I recognize this.
As for the line, I am clueless. What should I do for these types of problems?

Think geometrically. What are the points that are equi-distant from $0$ and $2$?

Would it be a line x = 1?

Yes, that is right.

Image of $\{x=1\}$. Let $u+iv=\frac  2{1-(1+iy)}=\frac  {2i} y$. Then, $u=0$ and $v=\frac 2 y$. Thus the image is the imaginary axis minus the origin.
